# Form.append() not sticking new created value

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I'm trying to append a parameter in a form with the following `JavaScript` code:

```
    function sendData(form) {
    const canuart = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch");
    var flag
    if (canuart.checked == true) {
        flag = "true"
    }else
        flag = "false"
    form.append("canuart", flag)
    form.submit()
}
```

The problem is that it does not stick the value of the flag variable to the `canuart` new created param.
This JavaScript function's purpose is to stick the status (checked = true / unchecked = false) of an input (Switch button) to a form and send the form. The switch button has to possible values, defined by the atributte `checked` (true and false) . I don't think my problem is within the HTML, but anyways here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
                <div class="uart-can">
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch"
                               tabindex="0" checked>
                        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-wrapper">
                    {% for state in states %}
                        <div class="button-{{ loop.index }}">
                            <p class="info">Turn on {{ state[0] }}</p>
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="to" onChange="sendData(this.form)" name="{{ state[0] }}"
                                       value="{{ state[1] }}">
                                {% if state[1]=='on' %}
                                    <span class="sliderTrue round"></span>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% if state[1]=='off' %}
                                    <span class="sliderFalse round"></span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

The form is sent and received by the backend, but when the Switch `checked` attribute is true, `append()` function sticks 'on' in the `canuart` form's parameter instead of `true`. This is something, but when the `checked` is false it doesn't even append the param to the form. What I want is to send a form with an additional param, named `canuart` and with the values true or false.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use the value in `onoffswitch` that is already submitted to the server?

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The think was that the checkbox wasn't sending anything when it was no checked. Thanks anyways.